# automatically submitting a php form after submission

Tags: javascript, php

First let me say I am not a PHP programmer at all, but I'm helping (or trying to) a client out on what should be a quick job of setting up a remote login page.

Essentially I have a 2 form field - user & password - that gets submitted to itself.  A string is built up using an ID, API Key, UTC timestamp, form username and form password.  This is converted to UTF-8 and then to base64.

This string then needs to be posted to a remote page as a form variable called strAuth.

I have the login form working and the string being built correctly, but not sure the best method about getting this to post again by itself.

```
<?php
  $bpid = '193493';
  $rkey = '3CE1334241ADA18CD';
  $ts = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp = time());
  $user = $_POST["user"];
  $pass = $_POST["pass"];
  $str = $bpid . ',' . $rkey . ',' . $ts . ',' . $user . ',' . $pass;
  $ustr = mb_convert_encoding($str,'UTF-8');
  $bstr = base64_encode($ustr);
```

The above builds a string that if I post manually checks out and works fine.  What's the best way to automatically post this using PHP?  I tried this but it generates a 2nd Submit button and doesn't automatically send the data.

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  echo "
<form action=\"remoteurltologin\" method=\"post\" id=\"loginForm\">
<input name=\"strAuth\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$bstr\">
<input type=\"submit\">
</form>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
   $('#loginForm').submit();
  </script>";
};
```

Thanks and sorry for the noob question!

Comment: You should look into cURL.

Comment: submission after submission, you mean, killing someone dead?

Comment: So, you want POST, for the remote server and then, re-post for the second url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with `curl` instead of printing form and submitting it in frontend:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'remoteurltologin',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'strAuth' => $bstr
    )
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Thanks - I think this is close, but it's not redirecting to the 'remoteurltologin' like a form action='remoteurltologinto' would.  It's expecting a response back and apparently the remote login page doesn't give a response back - it either logs in and sends to the correct page, or redirects to it's own login assistance page.

Comment: In `$resp` you have a response from the page you post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use cURL php library: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have jQuery script called, so use native javascript

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  echo "
<form action=\"remoteurltologin\" method=\"post\" id=\"loginForm\">
<input name=\"strAuth\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$bstr\">
<input type=\"submit\">
</form>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
   document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();
  </script>";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a submit button, remove:

```
<input type=\"submit\">
```

The button is only necessary to give people something to click to submit. In your case, it doesn't need to be there.

As for the form, give an input in the form `autofocus` and then use JS `onfocus` to submit.
PS: I wrapped the submit in a function.

```
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
      echo "
    <form action=\"remoteurltologin\" method=\"post\" id=\"loginForm\">
    <input name=\"strAuth\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$bstr\" autofocus onfocus='submitAgain()'>
    <input type=\"submit\">
    </form>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
     function submitAgain() {
       document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();
      }
      </script>";
    };
```